# Python subprocess with apostrophes, removes them

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, hbase, docker-exec

I'm running a command to my containerized Hbase DB from the `subprocess.run` function:

```
subprocess.run(('docker exec hbase bash -c "echo -e create "myTable", "R" | hbase shell"'), shell=True)
```

It seems that the command runs as I expected, it opens the HBase shell and then trying to execute the next command but without apostrophes: `create myTable, R`

The error I get:

```
2021-06-01 05:23:18,587 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
For Reference, please visit: http://hbase.apache.org/2.0/book.html#shell
Version 2.2.4, r67779d1a325a4f78a468af3339e73bf075888bac, 2020年 03月 11日 星期三 12:57:39 CST
Took 0.0032 seconds
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
create myTable, R
NameError: undefined local variable or method `myTable' for main:Object
```

HBase expects apostrophes around `myTable` and `R`.
I tried to run the same command prefixing the apostrophes with :

```
subprocess.run(('docker exec hbase bash -c "echo -e create \"myTable\", \"R\" | hbase shell"'), shell=True)
```

But I get the same results.

Any idea how can I prevent it from deleting the apostrophes?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try switching apostrophes? like double on the outside and single on the inside?

Comment: what do you mean? can you give an example, please?

Comment: If you're using `shell=True` you shouldn't put the command in a list.

Comment: does this work: `subprocess.run(("docker exec hbase bash -c 'echo -e create \'myTable\', \'R\' | hbase shell\""), shell=True)`

Comment: Actually no.. I'm getting the same results

Comment: You say apostrophes but you actually use double quotes.

Comment: I meant double quotes, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest double quotes like that.  Assuming we can correctly guess what you are attempting to say, try

```py
subprocess.run([
    'docker', 'exec', 'hbase', 'bash', '-c',
    '''echo 'create "myTable", "R"' | hbase shell'''])
```

which also conveniently gets rid of the [pesky `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess). (I also took out the `-e` from `echo -e` which didn't seem to be contributing anything useful. Probably prefer `printf` if you actually need that feature, anyway.)

Python provides triple quotes specifically so that you have a way to pass in both single and double quotes in a string if you need to. The shell accepts either single or double quotes around a string (though they have slightly different semantics -- single quotes quote completely verbatim, while double quotes are somewhat weaker) and so we use those around the argument to `echo`. Not quoting the argument would cause `bash` to parse and remove the quotes. (In the shell itself, you could equivalently say `echo "create \"myTable\", \"R\""` inside double quotes, with the literal double quotes escaped; but getting that through two additional layers of backslash quoting is going to get ugly. Both Python and `bash -c` want to do things with those backslashes.)